# How to find out what is causing my nodejs code to consume a lot of memory?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a nodejs process running, it is consuming more and more memory overtime. How can I figure out what is causing that much memory consumption, what variables are making the program consume so much memory?

I've tried using vscode debugger, but I can't seem to figure out much from it.

Are there any tools that can help me find out what is causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

This post details a variety of ways to approach and solve memory leak issues.

https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/04/03/how-to-track-and-fix-memory-leak-with-nodejs.html